# Laravel, Chart with multiple y-axes

Tags: javascript, laravel

I've started using the Laravel Charts with chart.js. I have a graph with 2 datasets but is want the datasets on a multi-axes graph.
The issue i run in to at the moment is the lack of documentation on this point.

This is the code i have at the moment:

```
$machine = Machine:all()->where('id', '1')->toArray();
$imestamp = array_column($machine, 'timestamp');
$totalActions = array_column($machine, 'total_actions');

$machine = Machine:all()->where('id', '2')->toArray();
$totalActions2 = array_column($machine, 'total_actions');

$totalActionsChart = new TotalActionsChart;
$totalActionsChart->labels($timestamp);
$totalActionsChart->dataset('Total Actions', 'line', $totalActions)->options([
    'borderColor' => '#003a7f',
]);
$totalActionsChart->dataset('Total Actions', 'line', $totalActions2)->options([
    'borderColor' => '#f18800',
]);

return view('machine', compact('totalOperationsChart'));
```

This code just shows a graph with 1 y axis and 2 datasets. When looking at the documentation of laravel charts or chart.js i cant find a example to make a graph with 2 y-axes. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the others who might run into this problem. 
After digging through the code of the laravel charts package i ran into this return statement:

```
return $this->options([
            'maintainAspectRatio' => false,
            'scales'              => [
                'xAxes' => [],
                'yAxes' => [
                    [
                        'ticks' => [
                            'beginAtZero' => true,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]);
```

i copied that options array and put in in mine and after adding a y axis in the y-axes array i suddenly had 2 y-axes. After playing around a bit more i found the solution to my problem.

```
$totalOperationsChart->options([
            'maintainAspectRatio' => false,
            'scales'              => [
                'xAxes' => [],
                'yAxes' => [ [
                            'type' => 'linear',
                            'display' => true,
                            'position' => 'left',
                            'id' => 'y-axis-1'],
                             [
                            'type' => 'linear',
                            'display' => true,
                            'position' => 'right',
                             'id' => 'y-axis-2'],
                            [
                            'ticks' => [
                                'beginAtZero' => true,
                            ],
                            'position' => 'right'],
                ],
            ],
        ]);
```

The array above is the solution to making a chart with 2 y-axes. 
After adding 2 y-axes you can bind your datasets to the specific y-axis. 
You can do that like this.

```
 $totalOperationsChart->dataset($chartTitle, $chartType, $dataset2)->options([
            'borderColor' => $borderColor2,
            'yAxisID' => 'y-axis-2'
        ]);
```